# CPT Parent as a page and CPT Child as a posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I have one CPT page named as books and one CPT post named as chapters, I am trying to achive this permalink structure here

```
book1->chapter11
book1->chapter12

book2->chapter21
book2->chapter22
```

and so on.

Here is my code for books cpt

```
register_post_type( 
        'books',
        $labels
        ,
            'public'                =>  true,
            'exclude_from_search'   =>  false,
            'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
            'show_ui'               =>  true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
            'show_in_menu'          =>  true,
            'show_in_admin_bar'     =>  true,
            'menu_position'         =>  100,
            'capability_type'       =>  'page',
            'map_meta_cap'          =>  true,
            'hierarchical'          =>  true,
            'supports'              =>  array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'author',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'comments',
                    'page-attributes',          
            ),
            'has_archive'           =>  true,
            'rewrite'               =>  array(
                    'slug'          =>  'book',
                    'with_front'    =>  true,
                    'feeds'         =>  true,
                    'pages'         =>  true
            ),
            'query_var'             =>  true,
            'can_export'            =>  true, 
        ) 

    );
```

and for chapters cpt

```
register_post_type( 
        'chapters',
$labels
,
            'public'                =>  true,
            'exclude_from_search'   =>  false,
            'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
            'show_ui'               =>  true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
            'show_in_menu'          =>  'edit.php?post_type=book',
            'show_in_admin_bar'     =>  true,
            'menu_position'         =>  100,
            'capability_type'       =>  'post',
            'map_meta_cap'          =>  true,
            'hierarchical'          =>  true,
            'supports'              =>  array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'author',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'comments',
                    'page-attributes',
                    'post-formats'                    
            ),
            'has_archive'           =>  true,
            'rewrite'               =>  array(
                    'slug'          =>  'book/chapter',
                    'with_front'    =>  true,
                    'feeds'         =>  true,
                    'pages'         =>  true
            ),
            'query_var'             =>  true,
            'can_export'            =>  true,           
        ) 

    );
```

these url's are working fine

```
localhost/library/book/html
localhost/library/chapter/preface
```

individually, but when I try this url

```
localhost/library/book/chapter/preface
```

currently as per my cpt settings, its gives me 404 error, I tried template redirect and rewrite flush also, but nothing works, now my question are

1. is it possible Parent as a page and Children as a posts?
2. if yes what's wrong with this code, am I am missing here?
3. my main concern is here url rewriting, it should be

   localhost/library/html/preface

where html is the name of the book and preface is the chapter.

I searched lot here but didn't get the solution it might look similar question to you, but really I need help.

thanks.

### Did some changes

like changed parent slug  to books and child slug to book/chapters and query_var to chapter so working fine for my question 1 and 2 now looking for 3 question url_rewriting.

thanks.

Comment: any suggestion??

Comment: You might care to check out the [Posts2Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin.

Comment: I am curious why you are trying to do this with multiple CPTs instead of one hierarchical CPT, which seems the obvious solution to me.

Comment: I'd also go with one CPT and parent-child entries, it seems like fulfilling all your needs for data management and URL handling.

Comment: ok, I guess for this situation one hierarchical CPT is better, I posted this to just get the idea about parent/child relationship on CPT, now my situation is this, I have 4 entities stores, brands, banks and coupons and they all are related to each other for example "pizza discount" coupon is related to some store "best buy" or bank "hdfc" as well as some category "fast food", I tried this way to differentiate every entity, and now stuck or working alternative on this but didn't find a better solution. Hope this clears your questions. Thanks for your comments.